# Deleting duplicate rows in Excel using Epplus

Tags: c#, .net, excel, spreadsheet, epplus

I have a worksheet with a number of rows and several columns. I want to delete all **duplicate** rows in this worksheet. In other words, the **highlighted** rows in this screenshot should be deleted, and the rows below should be moved up:

[image]

and should result in the following:

[image]

I'm using the following snippet of code:

```
List<int> rowsToDelete = new List<int>();
for (int row = 1; row <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; row++)
{
    string a = worksheet.Cells[row,1].Value.ToString();
    string b = worksheet.Cells[row,2].Value.ToString();
    string c = worksheet.Cells[row,3].Value.ToString();

    int i = row + 1;
    while (worksheet.Cells[i,1].Value.ToString().Equals(a) &&
           worksheet.Cells[i,2].Value.ToString().Equals(b) &&
           worksheet.Cells[i,3].Value.ToString().Equals(c))
    {
        rowsToDelete.add(i);
        i++;
    }
}
foreach (var row in rowsToDelete)
{
    worksheet.Delete(row);
}
```

It is not deleting the correct rows. How can I fix this?

This is using Epplus 4.5.3.3 and .NET Framework 4.6.1

Comment: You need to re-think this… the `while` loop… as soon as it finds a row that is NOT a duplicate then it will exit the `while` loop. Thus missing any rows below it that ARE duplicates. In addition, in the last `foreach` loop, deleting the rows is going to mess up the indexes on the next iteration of the first `for` loop since there are fewer rows. It is never a good idea to remove rows in a loop through those rows. If you want to delete the rows as you have I suggest a simple `for` loop that loops from the from the bottom up. Better would be to delete the rows after the loop.

Comment: @JohnG that is the purpose of the while loop, it should iterate through the duplicates only for a particular row. Could you provide a short example of what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only assume you are misunderstanding my comment in reference to the posted `while` statement…

```
while (worksheet.Cells[i,1].Value.ToString().Equals(a) &&
       worksheet.Cells[i,2].Value.ToString().Equals(b) &&
       worksheet.Cells[i,3].Value.ToString().Equals(c)) { …
```

This will work ONLY if the duplicate rows are contiguous. Example, using the first posted picture, lets assume there is a row nine (9) and in this row we have the “duplicate” cell values “a”, “b” and “c”. So when the `while` loop starts row 2 will evaluate to `true` as that row is a duplicate of row 1. So row index 2 is added to the list. On the next iteration of the `while` loop we will add row 3 as a duplicate. However, when we get to row 4, the `while` condition will evaluate to `false` as row 4 is NOT a duplicate of row 1. Therefore, the `while` loop will “EXIT” and the code will loop back up to the initial `for` loop to check the next row duplicates. At this point the duplicate at row 9 will never get checked thus leaving it as a duplicate row.

The point is that you do NOT want to stop checking for duplicate rows if one of the rows is NOT a duplicate. You need to continue through all the rows as the duplicate row could be on ANY row.

It should also be noted that it may be helpful to avoid “checking” for a duplicate row that has already been marked as a duplicate. Example, using the same first picture, in the first pass though the rows for the “first” row will add rows 2 and 3 as “duplicate” rows. So, when the `while` loop exits and we loop back up to the next row to check it will be row 2. However row 2 is ALREADY marked as a duplicate, so really there is no need to check that row for duplicates. In the solution below, a check will be made to see if the row that we are checking is already marked as a duplicate. If the row IS marked as a duplicate then we will simply skip that row.

Next, the last `foreach` loop to actually remove the rows may have some issues. Example, let’s say that the rows to remove list contains rows 2, 3 and 7. So inside the `foreach` loop... the code removes row 2. After this row is removed, then, row 3 is now row 2 and row 4 is now row 3 etc.… Therefore on the next iteration of the loop it will remove row 3 which is NOW row two (2). I hope it is clear that removing the rows in a top-down fashion WILL NOT WORK because as soon as the first row is removed, then all the row indexes below that row will change.

So, if we want to delete the proper rows in the list of row indexes, then, we can accomplish this by removing the rows from a bottom-up fashion. If we remove the rows from the bottom-up, then we do not have to worry about getting the indexes mixed up as we do when deleting the rows in a top-down fashion.

Given all this, I suggest you break this problem up into two steps. The first step simply fills the list of duplicate rows. Bear in mind, since we will be checking for the duplicate rows in a top-down fashion, the list of row indexes may not necessarily be in an ordered fashion. Example,  if we add a duplicate row 9 as previously suggested, then the list of row indexes to delete would be { 2, 3, 9, 7 }. The 9 is BEFORE the 7 because row 9 was found to be a duplicate of row 1 and row 7 was found to be a duplicate of row 6. The point here is that the list may not necessarily be in an ordered fashion and this will create problems as described above.

Therefore, after we get the list of row indexes to delete, we will SORT the list. This will set the list as { 2, 3, 7, 9 }. At this point we could simply start deleting the rows from the bottom of the list on up, OR in the example below we will simply REVERSE the list so it will become { 9, 7, 3, 2 }. Then we will have an ordered list of `ints` that are order from high to low. NOW the `for` loop through the list should work without mixing up the row indexes.

To help, I suggest you create a method that takes an open worksheet and returns our “unsorted” list of row indexes we want to delete. To simplify things, all the code does is add the row indexes of duplicate rows. Walking through the code below we start by looping through all the rows in the worksheet. If we get to a row that has already been marked as a duplicate, then we will skip that row.

If the row is not marked as a duplicate, then the code will start another `for` loop that starts on the next row and ends on the last row. Again if we get to a row that has already been marked as a duplicate, then we will skip that row. Once the code has looped through all the rows we simply return the list of row indexes to delete.

```
private List<int> GetDuplicateRowsToDelete(ExcelWorksheet worksheet) {
  List<int> rowsToDelete = new List<int>();
  string a, b, c;
  for (int i = 1; i <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; i++) {
    if (!rowsToDelete.Contains(i)) {
      a = worksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value.ToString();
      b = worksheet.Cells[i, 2].Value.ToString();
      c = worksheet.Cells[i, 3].Value.ToString();
      for (int j = i + 1; j <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; j++) {
        if (!rowsToDelete.Contains(j)) {
          if (worksheet.Cells[j, 1].Value.ToString().Equals(a) &&
                 worksheet.Cells[j, 2].Value.ToString().Equals(b) &&
                 worksheet.Cells[j, 3].Value.ToString().Equals(c)) {
            rowsToDelete.Add(j);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return rowsToDelete;
}
```

Finally we could make use of this method to get the indexes to delete, then we will sort and reverse the list, then delete the rows from the bottom up. Something like…

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(@"D:\Test\Excel_Test\RemoveDup1.xlsx");
  using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile)) {
    using (ExcelWorksheet worksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets[0]) {
      List<int> rowsToDel = GetDuplicateRowsToDelete(worksheet);
      rowsToDel.Sort();
      rowsToDel.Reverse();
      foreach (int rowIndex in rowsToDel) {
        worksheet.DeleteRow(rowIndex);
      }
      pck.Save();
    }
  }
  MessageBox.Show("Removed duplicates complete");
}
```

I hope this makes sense and helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved your issue in another way: I have created two extra columns, "CONCAT" and "COUNT":

- "CONCAT" contains the formula `=A2+B2+C2` (till the end of the array)
- "COUNT" contains the formula `==COUNTIF(D$2:D$9,D2)` (also till the end of the array)

From then on, just write a VBA macro, checking the values "E9" back to "E2" and in case the value is larger than 1, remove the entire row.